# ( PHP /JQuery?) Get the table row value when the checkbox is checked

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

It's a table, each row consists a checkbox, when it's checked, would like to get the respective td values and echo out. Here im using the if statement, but it doesn't seems to work.

And iam using php here, is using jquery a way out, can jquery work with php
code, so could i send those checked table row values back to serve? Any thoughts? Thank you.

```
  <form>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <?php

 $specific = []; 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {?>

 <td><input type="checkbox" name="p[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
 </td>

  <td><input type="text"  name="patientid[]" 
  style="border: none" value="<?php echo $row['patientid'] ?>"></td>

  <td>
  <textarea name="msg" style="border: none" class='msg'>
  <?php echo  $row['message'];} ?> </textarea>
  </td>

 <td><input class="phone" type="text" value="<?php echo 
 $row['telMobile'] ?>"></td>
```

check whether table row(s) are checked

```
  <?php if(!isset($_GET['p'])){

  $specific[] = [
                 "phone" => $row["telMobile"],
                 "message" =>$row["message"],

  ];}
  }  

  $result = json_encode($specific,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
  echo $result; 

  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
  echo "</form>";?>
```

The desired result for $result is to show only the data of the table row(s) that are `checked`.

```
 [{"phone":"123456","message":"test"},
 {"phone":"789456","message":"testing"}]
```

Comment: is there more code involved with this, is the last php snippet called via ajax call?

Comment: @flauntster I don't think he has used ajax and thats root of evil in this case

Comment: yes, haven't use ajax

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML code as below:

```
<td><input type="text"  name="patientid[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" 
  style="border: none" value="<?php echo $row['patientid'] ?>"></td>

  <td>
  <textarea name="msg[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" style="border: none" class='msg'>
  <?php echo  $row['message'];} ?> </textarea>
  </td>

 <td><input name="phone[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" class="phone" type="text" value="<?php echo 
 $row['telMobile'] ?>"></td>
```

I have added `<?php echo $row['id']; ?>` in the input control name.

Change your PHP code as below:

```
foreach($_GET["p"] as $id) {
   $specific[] = [
         "phone" => $_GET["phone"][$id],
         "message" => $_GET["msg"][$id],
       ];
}
```

Comment: The thing is the php code is within the form, so maybe cant use$_GET, as the form has submit yet

Comment: Do you want the solution for Javascript or PHP? In the PHP, you can only get the result if you submit the form.

Comment: i have tried to submit the form, but cant echo out the data

Comment: Did you copied text from my answer? I forgot to put ending bracket(];). $specific[] = [
         "phone" => $_GET["phone"][$id],
         "message" => $_GET["msg"][$id],
       ];

Comment: no, still not working, is if /else statement necessary, eg if the $row is checked, get the respective text value?

Comment: I have created a gist with sample code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b40136df15087bb8b0955a1ecbee33f3